# Powernap and Wake On LAN

Tags: 11.04, wakeonlan

I installed powernap on my headless Ubuntu 11.04 server and according to webmin the number of running tasks reduced from 105 to 89. 
The problem is that the server no longer wakes up from LAN (WOL)

When I send a WOL package either from my PC or iPod Touch the server does not respond. I need to go to the server and press the power button to get it running again.

I have proved that powernap causes the problem by uninstalling it, and then WOL works again.

How can I configure powernap so that it does not stop WOL from working?

Comment: Is PowerNap turning off the server or is PowerNap suspending the server? It might be a good idea for you to file a bug report in launchpad. Thank you!